# please explain sbegin = s ? s : *lasts;

Tags: c, string, pointers

could someone explain the following code snippet to me please, specifically the third line as it seems to be causing an error in my code:

```
char * (strtok_r)(char *s, const char *delimiters, char **lasts) {
    char *sbegin, *send;
    sbegin = s ? s : *lasts;
    ...
```

Im guessing its more like Im passing an incorrect pointer value or something but cant figure it out as Im not sure exactly how the function is doing what it does...

Ta

EDIT: Im not exactly sure the error that occurs either because the g$£&mn f*£$%^% Visual studio JIT debugger keeps trying to open all the time and messes everything up. grr..

Comment: Here's an [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) on it.

Comment: hmmm, may be its 
'if (s != NULL) {
  sbegin = s;
 } else {
  sbegin = *lasts;
 }'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equivalent to

```
if (s)
    sbegin = s;
else
    sbegin = *lasts;
```

To get more detail about `?:` operator, you could read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
sbegin = s ? s : *lasts;
```

is the same as:

```
if(s) 
    sbegin = s; 
else 
    sbegin = *lasts;
```

`?:` is called a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

This part of code is called [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

```
sbegin = s ? s : *lasts;
```

is equivalent of

```
if(s != null) sbegin = s
else sbegin = *lasts;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me, except the parentheses around `strtok_r` are a bit redundant and unusual.

The third line uses the *ternary* operator: It's a proper expression that represents a conditional. If the part before the question mark `?` evaluates to true (i.e. something other than `0`) the whole expression will have the value of the expression between `?` and `:`. Otherwise it will the expression after the colon `:`.

Since the types of `sbegin`, `s` and `*lasts` match, I see no problem there.

Comment: Somehow sbegin is still ending up with NULL after this expression is `s` is NULL ... so I'd guess my `lasts` isnt retaining its value correctly between calls... Aha! `lasts` islocal to the calling function so it gets wiped between calls to that function by *its* parent! cheers!

Comment: Jeez its great to be able to bounce ideas here, Id been tearing my hair out on where this bug came from after the code seemed to be working fine one min then dying the next.. If I could up vote more than once I would!